# Sudoku c++ como verificar si hay numeros repetidos en un array o un array multidimensional

Tags: c++

Lo único que tengo que hacer es agarrar un sudoku resuelto y verificar si el sudoku resuelto esta correcto.

Lo que no sé, es si hacer un array de "int sudoku[9][9]" o hacer un array por cada fila y columna

soy nuevo en c++

```
using namespace std;
int sudoku[9][9] =
{
{5,3,4,6,7,8,9,1,2},
{6,7,2,1,9,5,3,4,8},
{1,9,8,3,4,2,5,6,7},
{8,5,9,7,6,1,4,2,3},
{4,2,6,8,5,3,7,9,1},
{7,1,3,9,2,4,8,5,6},
{9,6,1,5,3,7,2,8,4},
{2,8,7,4,1,9,6,3,5},
{3,4,5,2,8,6,1,7,9}
};
}
```

Comment: Siendo estrictos las reglas del sudoku te obligan a verificar que: **1)** Solo numeros 1 al 9, **2)** No repeticiones en misma fila, **3)** No repeticiones en la misma columna,  **4)** No repeticiones en la misma región (9 submatrices de 3 x 3). Puede ser más o menos simple dependiendo de que te dejen usar (`std::sort`, `std::vector`, `std::unique`, `std::unordered_set`, arrays crudos al estilo C,...).  Creo que debes plantearte como vas a abordar el problema y decidir que estructura usar para almacenar en base a ello. Creo que dividir la matriz en partes puede complicarte para según que...

Comment: Aclara tu problema específico o añade detalles adicionales para destacar con exactitud lo que necesitas. Por la forma en que está escrito, es difícil determinar exactamente lo que quieres preguntar, este no es un servicio de resolución de tareas. Visita la página https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask para obtener ayuda sobre cómo aclarar esta pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reglas del *SUDOKU*:

1. Solo numeros 1 al 9,
2. No repeticiones en misma fila,
3. No repeticiones en la misma columna,
4. No repeticiones en la misma región (9 submatrices de 3 x 3).

:

```
/* Leer sudoku, 
    como vamos a leer digitos (1-9), los leemos de caracter en caracter.
    Para convertirlos de Ascii a entero, simplemente restamos el Ascii del '0'
    Si nos dan algo que no sea dígito, simplemente no será contado abajo.
*/
for(i=0;i<9;i++)
    for(j=0;j<9;j++)
    {
        scanf("%c",&c);
        a[i][j]=c-'0';
    }

/* Valida filas
    Revisamos cara campo del arreglo y guardamos cuales digitos ya
    encontramos, activando el bit correspondiente en una bandera de bits.
    Solo usaremos 9 de los 32 bits, así que si están los 9 digitos, la
    bandera tendrá el valor 0x01ff. Usaremos este valor para comparar.
*/
for(i=0;i<9;i++)
{
    flag=0x0000;
    for(j=0;j<9;j++)
        flag|=1<<(a[i][j]-1);
    if(flag!=0x01FF)
        reporta("fila",i,j-1);
}

/* Valida columnas
    Hacemos lo mismo que en las filas, haciendo el recorrido ahora 
    de forma "vertical"
*/
for(j=0;j<9;j++)
{
    flag=0x0000;
    for(i=0;i<9;i++)
        flag|=1<<(a[i][j]-1);
    if(flag!=0x01FF)
    reporta("col",i-1,j);
}

/* Valida bloques (3x3)
    Hacemos lo mismo que en las filas, pero en bloques de 3x3.
*/
for(si=0;si<3;si++)
{
    for(sj=0;sj<3;sj++)
    {
        flag=0x0000;
        for(i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<3;j++)
                flag|=1<<(a[si*3+i][sj*3+j]-1);

        }
        if(flag!=0x01FF)
            reporta("bloque",si*3+i-1,sj*3+j-1);
    }
}
printf("\nEl sudoku es correcto");
```

Esta solución no es propia, fue traducida del ingles, puedes verla [aquí](http://csourcecodes.blogspot.mx/2016/05/c-program-to-validate-sudoku-checking.html)

Comment: Octavio, si nos ayudaras a traducirla y agregar esta información a tu respuesta sería excelente!.

Comment: mira por favor [answer]... estaria bueno que mas alla del codigo, explicaras que hace para que la gente que entre en futuras ocasiones sepa como se usa.